# What is the final dependency scope when different scopes are specified for one JAR?

Tags: maven, maven-dependency

I am studying some JARs in the Maven Repository and discovered this:

- Hibernate Validator Engine 5.4.0.FINAL lists jboss-logging as a compile dependency, and jboss-logging-processor as a provided dependency
- jboss-logging-processor lists jboss-logging as a provided dependency

In general, when a JAR is mentioned multiple times along the way under different scopes, what is the final, actual scope? Is there an order of precedence of sorts?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context rather than inheritance.

However, if some implications are present:

- something is marked as `compile` it is implicitly a `runtime` dependency.
- something is marked as `runtime` it is implicitly a `test` dependency.
- `provided` will be used in both `runtime` and `test` though it is not loaded during run or test time.
- `system` will be used in both `runtime` and `test`

Comment: hmm I still don't get it. So say when I traverse the dependencies, a certain particular JAR is marked as a compile dependency for some and provided dependency for others, as an example, how do I determine what it is at the end?